# Api mailchimp agregar tags a un contacto

Tags: api, curl, update

buenas tardes me pueden apoyar en relación a la api?

Es sobre el actualizar los tags en una lista especifica para un usuario especifico.

Ya logro que se suscriban los usuarios que ingresan a  un formulario y logre también agregar un tag desde que se suscribe.

Pero el problema es cuando quiero agregar un nuevo tag a  un contacto que ya existe en una lista:
No me manda error la api
No actualiza el nuevo tag que quiero agregar

Les incluyo la función que estoy utilizando

```
  function rudr_mailchimp_subscriber_status( $email, $list_id, $api_key, $status ){
        $data = array(
            'apikey'        => $api_key,
        'email_address' => $email,
        'tags' => [ 'Asistencia' ],
        );
        $mch_api = curl_init(); // initialize cURL connection

      curl_setopt($mch_api, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://' . substr($api_key,strpos($api_key,'-')+1) . '.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/lists/' . $list_id . '/members/' . md5(strtolower($email)) );
        curl_setopt($mch_api, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json', 'Authorization: Basic '.base64_encode( 'user:'.$api_key )));
        curl_setopt($mch_api, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'PHP-MCAPI/3.0');
        curl_setopt($mch_api, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); // return the API response
        curl_setopt($mch_api, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "PUT"); // method PUT
        curl_setopt($mch_api, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);
        curl_setopt($mch_api, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
        curl_setopt($mch_api, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($data) ); // send data in json

        $result = curl_exec($mch_api);
        return $result;
    }
```

Comment: ¿Cuál es el error que te está dando? Es fundamental para poder ayudarte. Por favor pulsa en [edit] para agregarlo. Gracias.

Comment: Es que error no me sale de la respuesta de la api, simplemente pues manda como si agregara de nuevo el contacto pero no agrega el nuevo tag, digamos que no edita , tengo entendido por medio de la documentación que con el metodo put es con el que hace updates pero no me funciona

Comment: ¿Podrías intentar un `var_dump($result);` y decirnos lo que muestra? También sería bueno ver un `var_dump(http_build_query($data));`

Comment: Y me pregunto por qué mejor no usas `json_encode` para mandar los datos: `curl_setopt($mch_api, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($data) );`